# latexmk and xpdf previewing

Tags: viewers, preview, live-preview

I'm trying to use continuous updating with a combination of latexmk and xpdf. I set up my config file exactly as outlined in the latexmk documentation

```
$pdf_previewer = "start xpdf -remote %R %O %S";
$pdf_update_method = 4;
$pdf_update_command = "xpdf -remote %R -reload";
```

but when I try to open a file with `latexmk -pdf -pvc <file_name>.tex`, it opens a blank window with the following error: `Config Error: Invalid command syntax: '<file_name>.pdf'`

Any thoughts? I've tried opening the files directly with xpdf and they display fine, it's just when I try to open from latexmk in preview (-pvc or -pv) that it comes up with an error.

Recommendations such as "don't use xpdf" are also welcome, I'm new to this whole thing. I don't really want anything other than a simple preview, so the less bulky the viewer the better.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the commands mentioned in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655297/how-to-choose-a-different-pdf-viewer-for-latexmk-or-ps-viewer-dvi-viewer/655298#655298 ? (the parameters seem slightly different here)