# How to choose a different PDF viewer for latexmk? (or PS viewer/DVI viewer)

Tags: latexmk

**Short version:** How to choose a different PDF viewer for latemx?

**Long version/background:**
I use latexmk to "automatically" build my LaTeX projects (as it can be configured in a way that the PDF gets constantly updated whenever the source files are updated, which is quite neat (by calling: "latexmk -pvc -pdf awesomeDocument.tex")).

Although I am using a "normal PDF viewer" as system default (okular), it always starts a *browser* to display these PDFs, name google Chrome (so weird: I barely use that! I use Linux, so that's not even a default browser; strange world!).

I've tried finding this info in the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk?lang=en), but (apart form the fact that the font seems corrupted, you can barely read that document) it only mentions this for Windows, I think. I wasn't able to transfer this.

Answer (score 3):

*(I found the solution before even posting, I just thought I'd create this question for others, as I spend like 20 minutes finding this; which can now hopefully be reduced to a single minute using this question/answer.)*

On [some website](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html) I found the solution:

- Create new file, called `.latexmkrc` and put it into your home folder (`/home/yourUserName`)
- put in either one or all of the following commands, depending on which which file format you want to create:
  `$dvi_previewer = 'start xdvi -watchfile 1.5';`
  `$ps_previewer  = 'start gv --watch';`
  `$pdf_previewer = 'start evince';`
  Of course change the viewer name appropriately, e.g., okular instead of evince.